# sort map groupingBy counting

Tags: sorting, java-8, java-stream, counting, collectors

Is there way to sort map by value inside this collector without creation a new stream? 
Now it prints: AAS : 5 ABA : 195 ABC : 12 ABE : 52.
Desired: ABA : 195 ABE : 52 ...
getTrigraphStream(path) returns: HOW THE TRA GRI ONC GRI ONC INS WHE INS WHE

```
 public Map<String, Long> getTrigraphStatisticsMapAlphabet(String path) {
    return getTrigraphStream(path)
       .collect(groupingByConcurrent(Function.identity(),
           ConcurrentSkipListMap::new, counting()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there way to sort map by value inside this collector without
>   creation a new stream?

The answer is No. You can only sort by the value of the grouping **after you've finished grouping**.

Options:

1. You'll need to invoke the `stream()` method after grouping and sort by
   value then collect to a map.
2. use `collectingAndThen` with a finishing function to do the sorting
   and then collect to map.

i.e.

```
return getTrigraphStream(path)
       .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingByConcurrent(Function.identity(), counting()),
                  map -> map.entrySet().stream().sorted(....).collect(...)));
```

By the way, what's the problem with creating a new stream? it's a cheap operation.

Comment: or use a `SortedMap` maybe?

Comment: In this operation, there is no need to use a `ConcurrentSkipListMap`.

Comment: @nullpointer that sorts the map by keys as opposed to values I believe.